# Setting sub-domains on Nginx

Tags: configuration, nginx, subdomain

I have 2 application installed on my server using Nginx:

1. Rails application
2. wordpress blog

I want that the rails app will be accessible through: **staging.mydomain.com**
and that the wordpress blog will be accessible through: **blog.mydomain.com**

the site works fine but when i try to access the blog i get "*welcome to nginx*" screen.

here is my nginx config:

```
server {
     listen   80;
     server_name staging.mydomain.com;
     rails_env staging;

     access_log /srv/www/staging/www/logs/access.log;
     error_log /srv/www/staging/www/logs/error.log;

     location / {
          root   /srv/www/staging/www/current/trunk/web/public;
          passenger_enabled on;
          }

   }
   server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  blog.mydomain.com;


        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        access_log /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com/logs/access.log;
        error_log /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com/logs/error.log;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass   localhost:53217;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        }
    }
```

any thought about what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed! used this post: http://wiki.nginx.org/Wordpress

Comment: Can you update your answer on how you solved your problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change `server_name` for your blog to `blog.mydomain`:

```
server_name  test.mydomain.com;
```

I'm guessing you are trying to access blog.mydomain, but forgot to change `server_name`.

Try to use the `index` directive instead of `try_files`:

```
index index.php;
```

Also the `root` directive needs to point to the folder containing your index.php file:

```
root /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com; # should contain index.php
```

Comment: after changing the "index" im getting "404 Not Found"

Comment: Then you don't have an index.php at /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com/index.php. Is it in a subdirectory? Adjust your `root` directive.

Comment: nop, i can see the index file in: /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com/index.php, do i need to change something in the root?

Comment: You need to change the `root` directive to point to the directory with your index.php file.

Comment: so it point to the right place, since the index file is located at: /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Move directive `root /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com;` from `location {}` to `server {}` block.

And add location for root directory.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```